# What format is this?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

This is simple, but I don't know what to search to find my answer. Can someone please tell me in what format this data was inserted in the table ?

I want to read/insert/update it using PHP.

[image http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/4835/screenshot2011110813502.png](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/4835/screenshot2011110813502.png)

Here is the text:

> a:22:{s:12:"productimage";s:82:"/wp-content/uploads/products_img/bla.jpg";s:13:"productimage1";s:0:"";s:13:"productimage2";s:0:"";s:13:"productimage3";s:0:"";s:13:"productimage4";s:0:"";s:13:"productimage5";s:0:"";s:13:"productimage6";s:0:"";s:5:"price";s:2:"12";s:12:"spPrdLstDate";s:10:"2011-11-10";s:12:"specialprice";s:2:"11";s:6:"weight";s:1:"2";s:9:"istaxable";s:0:"";s:4:"size";s:5:"15,16";s:5:"color";s:3:"roz";s:10:"size_stock";s:4:",2,3";s:11:"color_stock";s:2:",1";s:19:"is_check_outofstock";s:2:"on";s:9:"initstock";s:2:"11";s:8:"minstock";s:1:"0";s:11:"isshowstock";s:2:"on";s:14:"affiliate_link";s:0:"";s:8:"posttype";s:7:"product";}

Comment: [serialize](http://php.net/manual/function.serialize.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an serialized array, you can [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) it to convert it back to the array type, and then [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) it back to string.

There is obviously a lot of debate on this being json or serialized data, but the length indicators for the upcoming string next to : clearly indicate a serialization.

```
$aArray = unserialize($sContents);
$sContents = serialize($aArray);
```

Comment: Yeah, it didn't look like json. I learned something new today. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's a serialized array
you can deserialize it with http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score -3):

That looks like Json, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON and http://www.json.org/