# Retrieving this type of arguement PHP

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What format is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050013/what-format-is-this)

How do i retrieve this one. I'm not sure if this is json or whatever this is called.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:13:"test@test.com";i:1;s:11:"yes@yes.com";}
```

I want to get the test@test.com and the yes@yes.com. How would I do that one?

This are dynamic values so it is not always like "test@test.com" or "yes@yes.com"

Thanks, anyhelp would be greatly appreciated and rewarded. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This content is serialized, likely using [`serialize`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), therefore you can "unwrap" it using [`unserialize`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) (don't know how *de-* serialize didn't come to mind in development, but hey):

```
$contents = unserialize($serialized);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's PHP serialized data .
To unserialize, use : [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

to get the data.

To be more precise :

```
$myData = 'a:2:{i:0;s:13:"test@test.com";i:1;s:11:"yes@yes.com";}';
$data = unserialize($myData);
$firstEMail = $data[0];
$secondEMail  = $data[1];
```